# I want to be able to load class from both root and sub path

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have a question.

My python project path is as below:

```
    code_root
    |
    - code_sub
    |    |- b.py
    |    -- c.py
    - a.py
```

imported c.py of code_sub from b.py.

so I want to be able to load b.py from both code_root and code_sub path.

for example:

```
    code_root>$ python nlp.py
```

or

```
    code_root/code_sub>$ python b.py
```

The problem here is to call c.py.

b.py should not import c.py like this:

```
    # b.py 
    import c
```

so i found my solution.

like below:

```
    from os.path import dirname
    curpath =  dirname(__file__)

    if len(curpath) == 0:
        curpath = '.'
    c = imp.load_source('c', curpath+'/c.py')
```

This works but it doesn't seem like the best solution.  Is there a more standard Python approach I could use to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually set my project as below and use fully qualified paths for my imports. Also, I highly recommend that you use virtual environments -- then you can use the command "add2virtualenv MyWorkinator, workinator" which makes imports much less complicated.

```
   MyWorkinator   (Project level folder)
    |
    - workinator   (All code here)
      |
      - package_a
        |
        - a1.py
        - a2.py
      - package_b
        |
        - b1.py
        - b2.py
      c.py
```

in c.py:

```
import workinator.package_b.b1
```

in b2.py:

```
import workinator.package_a.a1
```